# Active Storag を使って画像を投稿できるようにしたいのですが、投稿一覧ページに遷移すると、undefined method `images' for nil:NilClassとなってしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Active Storageを使ってコミュニティサイトを作ろうと考えていますが、投稿をしたあとにページ遷移をすると、
エラーになってしまいます
エラーメッセージは以下のとうりです

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `images' for nil:NilClass):
```

## 問題のソースコード

以下、投稿に関するモデル

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many_attached :images
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

以下userのモデルです

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  has_many :posts
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy

  delegate :name, :leaning_histry, :purpoose, :image, to: :profile
end
```

### ここからコントローラーを載せていきます

以下、投稿に関するコントローラー

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_post, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]

    def index
        @posts = Post.all
      end

      def new
      @post = Post.new
    end

    def edit
      @post = Post.find(post_params)
    end

    def create
      return redirect_to new_profile_path,alert: "プロフィールを登録してください" if current_user.profile.blank?
      @post = current_user
      @post = Post.create params.require(:post).permit(:content, images: []) 
      binding.pry
      if @post.save
        redirect_to root_path,notice:'投稿に成功しました'
        else
          render :new
        end
      end

      def update
        if @post.update(post_params)
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          render :edit
        end
      end

      def destroy
        if @post.destroy
          redirect_to root_path,alert: '投稿を削除しました'
        else
          redirect_to root_path
        end
      end

      private
        def post_params
          params.require(:post).permit(:content, images: [])
        end

        def find_post
          @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        end

        def force_redirect_unless_my_post
          return redirect_to root_path,alert:'権限がありません'if @post.user != current_user
        end
end
```

こちらが新規投稿ページです

```
<div class ='post-content'>
   <%= form_with model: @post, local: true  do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, :placeholder => "いまどんなカンジ？"%>
    <%= f.file_fifffeld :images, direct_upload: true, multiple: true %>
    <div class = 'submit-block'>
       <%= f.submit '投稿する', class:"button"%>
    </div>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

こちらが、投稿一覧を表示するページです

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-block">
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <div class="content">
         <div class="user-about">
         <div class="image">
             <%= image_tag 'user.JPG'%>
         </div>
         <div class="profile">
            <div class="name-history">
                <div class="name">
                    taka
                </div>
                <div class="mania-histry">
                    マニア歴：1年
                </div>
             </div>

             <div class="enjoy-point">
                 楽しいポイント: 自分の手で作ったものが動く様子が楽しい
             </div>
         </div>
       </div>

         <div class="text">
             <p><% post.content %></p>
         </div>

         <% if @post.images.attached? %>
         <div class = 'images'>
         <% @post.images.each do |image| %>
         <%= image_tag image %> <br>
         </div>
         <% end %>
         <% end %>


         <div class="action-menu">
             <div class="like">

             </div>
             <div class="comment">

             </div>
         </div>

        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
     <div class="box">

     </div>
     <div class="box">

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### ここから下がモデルの部分です

以下、投稿に関するモデルです

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many_attached :images
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

こちらが、userのモデルです

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  has_many :posts
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy

  delegate :name, :mania_histry, :enjoy_point, :image, to: :profile
end
```

## やってみたこと

rails cでpost.allとやって投稿をconsole上で取り出してみようと思い、取り出してみたのですが、画像が、出て来なかったので、おそらくDB上に保存されていないのだと思います。

もう一つが、
Active Storageを実装するにあたってgenereta resourceを実行すると調べたところ下記の記事には書いてありました。

[【Rails 5.2】 Active Storageの使い方](https://qiita.com/hmmrjn/items/7cc5e5348755c517458a)

その時僕は、そのコマンドを実行していませんでした、
それが原因なのかなと思っているんですけど、解決の糸口は見つけられていないです。

`rails c`で`post.all`とやって投稿をコンソール上で取り出してみようと思い、取り出してみたのですが、画像は出て来ませんでした。

Comment: f.file_fifffeld という文字列がありますが、これはミスタイプでしょうか？それとも、実際にこのコードが動いているのでしょうか？ rails consoleで「画像が出てこない」というのは具体的には何が起きたのでしょうか？実行したコマンドとその結果をコピペしてもらえると解決の糸口になると思います。

Answer (score 1):

Yusuke Sangenya さんにご指摘いただいた通り、`f.file_fifffeld` となっていた誤字を修正した後、`<% @post.images.each do |image| %>`の部分と`<% @post.images.each do |image| %>`にある@postの部分をpostに修正したら無事解決しました。
ありがとうございました。